# Why am I getting a "no data is present" error after passing the "HasRows" test?

Tags: vb.net, invalidoperationexception, no-data

I've got this code:

```
Protected Function GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName As String) As String()
    Dim args(2) As String
    Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("SERVER=PLATYPUS42;DATABASE=duckbilldata;UID=durante;PWD=pondscum")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    cmd.CommandText = "select Unit, MemberNo, CustNo from Customers WHERE CompanyName = @CoName"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CoName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = coName
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1
    sqlConnection1.Open()

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.HasRows Then
            args(0) = reader.Item(0).ToString()
            args(1) = reader.Item(1).ToString()
            args(2) = reader.Item(2).ToString()
    End If
    reader.Close()
    sqlConnection1.Close()

    Return args
End Function
```

...which fails on this line:

```
args(0) = reader.Item(0).ToString()
```

...with:

```
*System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.*
```

How can it be that it "HasRows" and yet there is no data present?

NOTE: It also fails with the same error when I try this (instead of using the "0" index):

```
args(0) = reader.Item("Unit").ToString()
```

### UPDATE

The accepted answer works fine in modern apps (e.g., my "sandbox" Windows forms app), but in olden apps, such as a creaky, archaic web site, which uses .NET prehistoric, it doesn't- the "usings" are apparently unrecognized; I get:

```
Server Error in '/EMS/customerreportingnet' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. 

Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30203: Identifier expected.

Source Error:

Line 90:         Dim args(2) As String
Line 91: 
Line 92:         Using con As New SqlConnection("SERVER=PLATYPUS42;DATABASE=duckbilldata;UID=durante;PWD=pondscum"),
Line 93:               cmd As New SqlCommand("select Unit, MemberNo, CustNo from Customers WHERE 

CompanyName = @CoName", con)
Line 94: 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5491
```

Comment: To address the issue with an archaic compiler which can't handle `Using`, you can hand-implement it using a `Try`-`Finally`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say in your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42933745/6375113), a call to `.Read` is required.

The `If reader.HasRows` however isn't required. The `Do While reader.Read` will handle this. If there are rows then it will enter the loop, otherwise it will bypass.

As an additional note, I think it would be beneficial to implement [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx):

```
Protected Function GetArgValsForCompanyName(coName As String) As String()
    Dim args(2) As String

    Using con As New SqlConnection("SERVER=PLATYPUS42;DATABASE=duckbilldata;UID=durante;PWD=pondscum"),
          cmd As New SqlCommand("select Unit, MemberNo, CustNo from Customers WHERE CompanyName = @CoName", con)

        con.Open()

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CoName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = coName

        Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

            While reader.Read
                args(0) = reader.Item(0).ToString()
                args(1) = reader.Item(1).ToString()
                args(2) = reader.Item(2).ToString()
            End While

        End Using

    End Using

    Return args
End Function
```

With `Using` you don't have to worry about calling `.Close` or the disposing of objects. I also feel it reads better.

Answer (score 0):

A call to "read" is also required; this works (either name of field returned or its index can be used):

```
If reader.HasRows Then
    Do While reader.Read
        'args(0) = reader.Item(0).ToString()
        args(0) = reader.Item("Unit").ToString()
        args(1) = reader.Item(1).ToString()
        args(2) = reader.Item(2).ToString()
    Loop
End If
```